# PHP form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Been trying editing a script i found in W3 school.

Edit:
I want to have a search text box. I can enter data in it and it will trigger the PHP script and return the value without reloading the homepage. So when i enter "404040" and click search button it should do this adminsearchvip.php?q=404040
then return the value without reloding the homepage.
 end of edit.

The original script is a dropdown menu but i want a textboxt insted.

I am not sure if the code for the send "Submit" button is correct.

First file searchvip.php

```
    <html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser()
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","adminsearchvip.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<label for="Number"></label>
<input type="text" name="Number" id="Numbers" value="">
<input type='button' onclick='showUser(Numbers.value)' value='Search' />
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the script it self.

adminsearchvip.php

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','xxxxxx','xxxxx','jossan');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"jossan");
$sql="SELECT * FROM vip_stat WHERE code = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Bought Date</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Used</th>
<th>Activation Date</th>
<th>Username</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['used'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['utime'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have tested to go the www.homepage.com/adminsearchvip.php?q=9494943 with my webbrowser and that works i get the correct respons. So the script seems to work. But the search page does not even show anything.

Comment: If by "WC3 school" you mean w3schools, you really shouldn't read anything they publish. To find out why, take a look at http://www.w3fools.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, i would suggest you give jquery a try.

link to Jquery on your page's head section,

```
showUser()
{
 var url='adminsearchvip.php';
 var q = $("#Numbers").val();
 $("#txtHint").html('Loading Please Wait...');
 $.get(url,{ q: q } ,function(data){  $("#txtHint").html(data) }); 
}
```

This should do it for you.

Since its a search, am using `$.get` if its a post request, use `$.post`. Let me know if you find any more issues

here is a link to jQuery hosted by google CDN
`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js`

This is how your form should look like

```
<form>
<label for="Number"></label>
<input type="text" name="Number" id="Numbers" value="">
<input type='button' onclick='javascript: showUser();' value='Search' />
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the effort, ive been strugling with this some time now. Read some at jquery faq as well. Cant get it to work at all.

How should the button form look like?

<form>
<label for="Number"></label>
<input type="text" name="Number" id="Numbers" value="">
<input type='button' onclick='showUser()' value='Search' />
</form>

Comment: @ZaraRebeckaElisabethZentio  i have updated my answer take a look at the html form.

Comment: THank you i kinda solved it now i just need to work on the display part :) THanks so much for putting in time on this

Answer (score 1):

> "Been trying editing a script i found in W3 school."

Well, there's your problem. [Don't use W3 schools](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Since you want to load an html table using ajax and insert it into your dom when a user clicks a button, you could use [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to easily accomplish this task. Here is a rough example:

```
//note: put id="buttonId" on the button element in order for this to work
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
    var value = $('#Numbers').val();
    if (value !== '') {
        $('#txtHint').load("adminsearchvip.php?q="+value);
    }
});
```

By the way, you should use a prepared statement in your adminsearchvip script instead of concatenating the $q variable to your sql.

Comment: What i try to do is have a javascript to display information from a mysql table without reloading.

Comment: +1 Rob Apodaca for the jquery insight. Try using jquery to accomplish your request. That will be a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. Am not good at all with this stuff i am very new but try to learn by doing as just reading dont work for me. I looked some at Jquery homepage about forms and such but i dident really understand it all as i could not find anything with MYSQL examples. Can you maybe give me a snippet or something to play around with that uses Jquery and mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Do Change Following line

```
<input type='button' onclick='return showUser()' value='Search' />
```

Now Add One Line in your function showUser.

```
function showUser()
{
  var str = document.getElementById("Number").value;
```

Now let me know if you have still issue.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, it still does not work. Is there some way i can add some text to the div so i can debugg what it really sends?